# How can I enable Onclick event of other table rows using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have difficulties in enabling the onclick event in jquery.

this my HTML, it is table with data in it, when you click a row, it will transfer the static value inside the input box. I also have the edit and save function. I want to put a function inside the edit button where in after clicking the edit button, the table will now be disable to prevent the user to click on other row inside the table, i have already have a function where in I disable the onclick event so that the value inside the input box will not change, but after clicking save, it will get stuck on the selected row even if you click on other row.  Now i have no idea on how to enable back the table again after clicking the save button so that the user can select other rows again. if you have any code idea on disable/enable the table, please just let me know. thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Highlight row when selected.
    $(function () {
        $('#Cases tr').click(function () {
            $('#Cases tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
            $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
        });
    });

    //Display selected row data in text input.
    var table = document.getElementById("Cases"), rIndex;

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
            rIndex = this.rowIndex;
            console.log(rIndex);

            document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("Department").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("Charge").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("LabCase").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
        };
    } 
 

     //Disable or enable input box 
        $("#DepartmentCase").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#Department").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#Charge").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#LabCase").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);


    //Edit Button Function

    $("#Edit").click(function () {
       $('#Cases tr').removeAttr('onclick');
        $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Department").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Charge").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", false).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $("#Edit").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", false);
    });

    //Save Button Functions
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Department").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Charge").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("LabCase").value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value;
        $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#dialog-1").dialog("open");
      
    });

    //For dialog box
     $("#dialog-1").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });
    
    //Cancel Button Function

    $("#Cancel").click(function () {
        $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);




    });


});
```

```css
#Cases {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#Cases td, #cases th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#Cases tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
#Cases tr.selectedRow{background-color: #56bff0}
#Cases tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
#Cases tr{cursor: pointer}
#Cases th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #455382;
  color: white;
}
#container{
        margin:0 auto;
        width:80%;
        overflow:auto;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<html>


<body>


<h2>
        Recent Cases
    </h2>
    <table id="Cases">
  <tr>
    <th>Department Case #</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Charge</th>
    <th>Lab Case #</th>
    <th>Incident Report Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-383</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2011</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-321</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-456</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2012</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-789</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Duping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-356</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2014</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-297</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2015</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-393</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Duping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-382</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-023</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-083</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2019</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p><b>Case Details</b></p><br />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Department Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department Case #"  id="DepartmentCase" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Department</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department"  id="Department" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Charge</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Charge"  id="Charge" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lab Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Lab Case"  id="LabCase" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Incident Report Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Incident Report Date"  id="IncidentReportDate" value=""/></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br/>


<table> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" onclick=""/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Save" id="Save" onclick=""/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
     rel = "stylesheet">
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
  <html>


 <body>


 <h2>
     Recent Cases
</h2>
<table id="Cases">
  <tr>
<th>Department Case #</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Charge</th>
<th>Lab Case #</th>
<th>Incident Report Date</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-383</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2011</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-321</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2019</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-456</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-789</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Duping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2013</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-356</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2014</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-297</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2015</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-393</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Duping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2016</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>123-12345-1234-382</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2017</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>123-12345-1234-023</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2018</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>123-12345-1234-083</td>
<td>Forti-Palmade</td>
<td>Illegal Dumping</td>
<td>10-123456</td>
<td>05/03/2019</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<p><b>Case Details</b></p><br />

 <table>
<tr>
<td>Department Case #</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Department Case #"  id="DepartmentCase" value=""/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Department</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Department"  id="Department" value=""/></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>Charge</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Charge"  id="Charge" value=""/></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>Lab Case #</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Lab Case"  id="LabCase" value=""/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Incident Report Date</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Incident Report Date"  id="IncidentReportDate" value=""/></td>
</tr>

 </table>
 <br/>


  <table> 
 <tr>
 <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" onclick=""/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Save" id="Save" onclick=""/></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

 </html>
```

This is my jquery/javascript for

```
//Display selected row data in text input.

    var table = document.getElementById("Cases"), rIndex;

      for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
         table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
    rIndex = this.rowIndex;
    console.log(rIndex);

    document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("Department").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("Charge").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("LabCase").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
   };
 }
```

this the js for the edit and save

```
 $("#Edit").click(function () {
 $('#Cases tr').removeAttr('onclick');
 $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", false);
 $("#Department").prop("disabled", false);
 $("#Charge").prop("disabled", false);
 $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", false);
 $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", false).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
 });
 $("#Edit").prop("disabled", true);
 $("#Save").prop("disabled", false);
 $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", false);
});

  //Save Button Functions
  $("#Save").click(function () {
  table.rows[rIndex].cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value;
  table.rows[rIndex].cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Department").value;
  table.rows[rIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Charge").value;
  table.rows[rIndex].cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("LabCase").value;
  table.rows[rIndex].cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value;
  $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#dialog-1").dialog("open");

  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to disable/enable table event listeners, you could more simply store the editing state in a variable and check it before doing any action that should be disabled while editing.
I modified your code to implement this idea ; editing state is stored in the `isEditing` variable. All modifications are highlighted by a `// new code` comment line.

#### update

In response to your comment, I also refactored the code by introducing `setEditingState` method that reduces code duplication.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // new code
    var isEditing;

    //Highlight row when selected.
    $(function() {
        $('#Cases tr').click(function() {
            // new code
            if (isEditing) {
                return;
            }

            $('#Cases tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
            $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
        });
    });

    //Display selected row data in text input.
    var table = document.getElementById('Cases'), rIndex;

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
            // new code
            if (isEditing) {
                return;
            }

            rIndex = this.rowIndex;
            console.log(rIndex);

            document.getElementById('DepartmentCase').value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('Department').value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('Charge').value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('LabCase').value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('IncidentReportDate').value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
        };
    }


    // new code
    setEditingState(false);
    // Init date picker.
    $('#IncidentReportDate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

    //Edit Button Function
    $('#Edit').click(function() {
        // new code
        setEditingState(true);
    });

    //Save Button Functions
    $('#Save').click(function() {
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById('DepartmentCase').value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById('Department').value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById('Charge').value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById('LabCase').value;
        table.rows[rIndex].cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById('IncidentReportDate').value;
        $('#dialog-1').dialog('open');

        // new code
        setEditingState(false);
    });

    //For dialog box
    $('#dialog-1').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });

    //Cancel Button Function
    $('#Cancel').click(function() {
        // new code
        setEditingState(false);
    });

    // new code
    // Adapt UI to editing state.
    function setEditingState(editing) {
        // Store value.
        isEditing = editing;
        // Disable/enable fields.
        $('#DepartmentCase').prop('disabled', !editing);
        $('#Department').prop('disabled', !editing);
        $('#Charge').prop('disabled', !editing);
        $('#LabCase').prop('disabled', !editing);
        $('#IncidentReportDate').prop('disabled', !editing);
        // Disable/enable buttons.
        $('#Edit').prop('disabled', editing);
        $('#Save').prop('disabled', !editing);
        $('#Cancel').prop('disabled', !editing);
    }
});
```

```css
#Cases {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#Cases td, #cases th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#Cases tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
#Cases tr.selectedRow{background-color: #56bff0}
#Cases tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
#Cases tr{cursor: pointer}
#Cases th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #455382;
  color: white;
}
#container{
        margin:0 auto;
        width:80%;
        overflow:auto;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<html>


<body>


<h2>
        Recent Cases
    </h2>
    <table id="Cases">
  <tr>
    <th>Department Case #</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Charge</th>
    <th>Lab Case #</th>
    <th>Incident Report Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-383</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2011</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-321</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-456</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2012</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-789</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Duping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-356</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2014</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-297</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2015</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-393</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Duping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-382</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-023</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123-12345-1234-083</td>
    <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
    <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
    <td>10-123456</td>
    <td>05/03/2019</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p><b>Case Details</b></p><br />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Department Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department Case #"  id="DepartmentCase" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Department</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Department"  id="Department" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Charge</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Charge"  id="Charge" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lab Case #</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Lab Case"  id="LabCase" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Incident Report Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Incident Report Date"  id="IncidentReportDate" value=""/></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br/>


<table> 
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" onclick=""/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Save" id="Save" onclick=""/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it works and it helped me a lot! thank you also for modifying the highlight function, it really helps.

Comment: hello, i can ask a question again, as you can see in the javascript part, there is function where in a disable and enable button/textbox when a certain button is clicked and every function I placed the same code which makes it redundant.  (example : when edit button is clicked, the input box,save and cancel button is enable and vice versa). is there any way wherein i can reuse the same line of code and call it everytime i need  it.

Comment: Yes, of course, I edited my answer, including a method for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a flag variable called `edit` and set it to `false` when you're click save or cancel and to `true` when you're editing:

```js
if (edit) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var edit = false;
  //Highlight row when selected.
  $(function() {
    $('#Cases tr').click(function(e) {
      if (edit) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
      rIndex = this.rowIndex;
      //console.log(rIndex);

      document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("Department").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("Charge").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("LabCase").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
      $('#Cases tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
      $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
    });
  });
  var table = document.getElementById("Cases");

  //Disable or enable input box 
  $("#DepartmentCase").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#Department").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#Charge").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#LabCase").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#IncidentReportDate").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);


  //Edit Button Function

  $("#Edit").click(function() {
    edit = true;
    //$('#Cases tr').removeAttr('onclick');
    $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Department").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Charge").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", false).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
    $("#Edit").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Save").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", false);
  });

  //Save Button Functions
  $("#Save").click(function() {
    edit = false;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[0].innerHTML = document.getElementById("DepartmentCase").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[1].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Department").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[2].innerHTML = document.getElementById("Charge").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[3].innerHTML = document.getElementById("LabCase").value;
    table.rows[rIndex].cells[4].innerHTML = document.getElementById("IncidentReportDate").value;
    $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#dialog-1").dialog("open");

  });

  //For dialog box
  $("#dialog-1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
  });

  //Cancel Button Function
  $("#Cancel").click(function() {
    edit = false;
    $("#DepartmentCase").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Department").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Charge").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#LabCase").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#IncidentReportDate").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Edit").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#Save").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Cancel").prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```css
#Cases {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#Cases td,
#cases th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#Cases tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

#Cases tr.selectedRow {
  background-color: #56bff0
}

#Cases tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#Cases tr {
  cursor: pointer
}

#Cases th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #455382;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<html>


<body>


  <h2>
    Recent Cases
  </h2>
  <table id="Cases">
    <tr>
      <th>Department Case #</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Charge</th>
      <th>Lab Case #</th>
      <th>Incident Report Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-383</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2011</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-321</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2019</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-456</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-789</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Duping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-356</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-297</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-393</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Duping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-382</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-023</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123-12345-1234-083</td>
      <td>Forti-Palmade</td>
      <td>Illegal Dumping</td>
      <td>10-123456</td>
      <td>05/03/2019</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p><b>Case Details</b></p><br />

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Department Case #</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Department Case #" id="DepartmentCase" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Department</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Department" id="Department" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charge</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Charge" id="Charge" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lab Case #</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Lab Case" id="LabCase" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Incident Report Date</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Incident Report Date" id="IncidentReportDate" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <br/>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="Edit" onclick="" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank so much the disable table while editing works! just what i've been looking for. i just need to modify my code so that the highlight function will not change if there is selected row already. thank you very much !